# Return to refreshed previous page from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've seen some posts dealing with the same issues but i couldn't find any solution that worked for me. One of my "Edit" page is called from several others. But when I do click on the "Save"button, I'd like to be redirected to the previous page, refreshed with the information I've just changed.

Is there a way in the Controller to return something similar as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to previous page", null, null, null, new { onclick = "history.go(-1);"})
```

Comment: What if you just pass a link to the current page as a query string parameter to the edit page?

Comment: Check TempData: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ***Request.UrlReferrer***. However, it is ***not a reliable way*** of detecting where the user comes from.

### First Approach

The easiest approach is to append ***ReturnUrl*** in query string. *It is very common and we normally see at Login page of many websites.*

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Do something
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

### Second Approach

If you do not want to see ReturnUrl in query string, you can use ***SessionState***.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Do something
        if (Session["ReturnUrl"] != null)
            return Redirect(Session["ReturnUrl"].ToString());
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

In either approach, original page has the responsibility of providing Return URL. It is the small price you will have to pay if you want a reliable mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I guess I should have some kind of problem... No matter what I try, when I click "Save edits", it looks like the page refreshes. The modifications are made in the databases though :-/

Comment: It seems like different problem than original question. Could you create a new question? I could take a look at it.

Comment: So sorry !!! Your second approach is perfectly working. I forgot to put Session["ReturnUrl"] in the method for the original page... My bad. So tired I make silly mistake. Thank you so much! But still don't understand why the "Request.UrlReferrer" doesn't work... Anyway Thank you so much. I think I'll manage with your solution

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
return Redirect(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```

I used a similar approach in previous projects, where i had a BaseController with the method.

```
protected ActionResult GoBack()
{
    try
    {
        return Redirect(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       TempData["ErrorHeader"] = "Some kind of Error header";
       TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Some kind of Error message";
       logger.Error("Add ErrorMessage here",ex);

       return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");

    }
}
```

**Updated with better exception handling

Comment: Looks _very_ strange to me; eating an exception is something I always try to avoid.

Comment: @Uwekeim Yep I do agree. It is also not 100% identical to the way i implemented it earlier, this is just to show the general idea. Just to clarify i removed all references to the logging framework i used, and the way i returned the error to the client

Comment: Thank you @MikNiller ! I tried and try against obviously, but it seems that this returns the current page i.e the "Edit" page, not the previous one. I don't really understand, cause others seemed to be satisfied with this solution.

Comment: @Pookey, the above will only work if you come from page A, then goes to page B and want to return to page A.

If your logic is more complicated, e.g. you come from page A, then continues to page B and makes a post to page B again, the GoBack method will bring you back to first visit to page B.

Comment: @MikNiller Aannnnw okay ! That makes sense actually ! Thank you !! I guess this drove me a little bit crazy this afternoon...